# SQLITE insert android oncreate block

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this insert statement, it works fine in on create method but what i want is that i don't want to run this in on create every time. i just want this to run only one time. can any one give me some hint or solution regarding this.

**MainActivity**

```
public class ListConfigActivity extends Activity {    
DBAdapter myDb;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_config);

    openDB();
        myDb.insertRow("Default", "10/13/2014" , 1204, "True", "True");
}
```

**DBAdapter.java**

```
public class DBAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

//DB fields
public static final String KEY_config = "_idconfiguracao";
public static final String KEY_Descricao = "descricao";
public static final String KEY_DataCriacao = "data_criacao";
public static final String KEY_Usuario = "usuario";
public static final String KEY_Ativo = "ativo";
public static final String KEY_Default = "defaultconfig";

//Setup fields numbers here
public static final int COL_idConfig = 0;
public static final int COL_Descricao = 1;
public static final int COL_DataCriacao = 2;
public static final int COL_Usuario = 3;
public static final int COL_Ativo = 4;
public static final int COL_DefaultConfig = 5;

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[]
{ KEY_config, KEY_Descricao, KEY_DataCriacao, KEY_Usuario, KEY_Ativo, KEY_Default };

//DB info: name and table
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "jornada";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "configuracao";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
        + "("   +   KEY_config          + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                +   KEY_Descricao       + " string not null, "
                +   KEY_DataCriacao     + " text not null, "
                +   KEY_Usuario         + " integer not null, "
                +   KEY_Ativo           + " string not null, "
                +   KEY_Default         + " string not null"
        + ");" ;

// context of application who uses us.
private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper myDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter (Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

// open database connection
public DBAdapter open()
{
    db = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// close database connection
public void close()
{
    myDbHelper.close();
}

// add new set of values to the database
public long insertRow(String descricao, String data_criacao, int usuario, String ativo,   String defaultconfig)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_Descricao, descricao);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DataCriacao, data_criacao);
    initialValues.put(KEY_Usuario, usuario);
    initialValues.put(KEY_Ativo, ativo);
    initialValues.put(KEY_Default, defaultconfig);
    Log.i("Insert record", initialValues.toString());
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public boolean updateRow(long configID, String descricao, String data_criacao, int usuario, String ativo, String defaultconfig)
{
    String where = KEY_config + "=" + configID;

    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_Descricao, descricao);
    newValues.put(KEY_DataCriacao, data_criacao);
    newValues.put(KEY_Usuario, usuario);
    newValues.put(KEY_Ativo, ativo);
    newValues.put(KEY_Default, defaultconfig);

    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide some more detail?  Are you running this from a content provider? An Activity?  Is myDb a SQLiteDatabase or something else?

Comment: @MichaelKrause i have edit my question now you can see what is myDb

Comment: make DBadapter static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to insert that one row exactly once, I would consider making it part of the database creation method: `DBAdapter::onCreate()`. Simply add another _db.execSQL with the insert SQL statement to insert your row.  That way, this row will be added to the database exactly once. It would then read

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
    _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
    _db.execSQL(DATABASE_ADD_DEFAULT_ROW);
}
```

Alternatively, assuming I understand your code correctly, you could use the exact same call as you do in the Activity's onCreate:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
    _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
    _db.insertRow("Default", "10/13/2014" , 1204, "True", "True");
}
```

EDIT: @superfell correctly points out in the comments that you must delete the existing DB for this onCreate method to be called again.  You can achieve this easily enough by manually uninstalling the app from the test device/emulator.

Comment: @emersso i need to how can i put my insert query here ? can you please write it ?

Comment: i actually did this but nothing happen, even log is not showing anything

Comment: did you delete your db so that it gets created again?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering why you want to do this, but well this is an idea using `preferences`:

```
   public class ListConfigActivity extends Activity {    
    DBAdapter myDb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_config);

    if(getIsDataInserted(getApplicationContext())){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Row Already Inserted!", 1).show();
    }else{
        openDB();
        myDb.insertRow("Default", "10/13/2014" , 1204, "True", "True");
        setIsDataInserted(getApplicationContext(), true); //Data inserted !
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Row Inserted!", 1).show();
    }
  }
```

add to methods, to set a boolean indicating the row is inserted (true) and another to get the value (true or false)

```
public static void setIsDataInserted(Context context, boolean data){
    context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_SYSTEM", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("insert_data", data);
}   

public static boolean getIsDataInserted(Context context){       
    return context.getSharedPreferences("PREFS_SYSTEM", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("insert_data", false);
}
```

I think you will use a button to do this action too, or use the method suggested by emerssso

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
    _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
    _db.execSQL(DATABASE_INSERT_ROW); //Insert the row only when the database is created.
}
```

Comment: i want to do this because i want to use this " myDb.insertRow("Default", "10/13/2014" , 1204, "True", "True");" first row from bank. until user use other interface to add new row. i am not sure if this is the right way..